# Google App Engine Standard and Flex in same project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, app-engine-flexible

I am new to App Engine Flex and know a little on App Engine Standard. I want to use both in the same project so that I can use the App Engine Standard for receiving emails and the flex environment for cron jobs / backend jobs using Python3. Is it possible to use both App Engine Standard and App Engine Flex in the same project or does it has to be different?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Quote from the [Google App Engine doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments) (emphasis added):

> You can run your applications in App Engine using the flexible
>   environment or standard environment. **You can also choose to
>   simultaneously use both environments** for your application and allow
>   your services to take advantage of each environment's individual
>   benefits.